# WP8 DateTime.TryParse fails unless given a literal string

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datetime, windows-phone-8

I was porting my Windows Phone 7 application to Windows Phone 8, and this code:

```
DateTime.TryParse(times, out correctTime);
```

where times is equal to a time of day, say 7:58 PM, fails on Windows Phone 8 and returns the minimum DateTime value, whereas on Windows Phone 7 the code worked perfectly.

Interestingly enough, on Windows Phone 8, when times is equal to "7:58 PM" it will fail. However if I replace times with a string literal equal to "7:58 PM" the code works fine.

So string literals work fine, and the code on WP7 works fine, but the code wont work on WP8 without literals.

I cannot figure this out. Can any of you help?

Comment: Could it be that Phone 7 and Phone 8 have different time formats (e.g. `0-24` on Phone 7 and `AM/PM` on Phone 8)?

Comment: I'm am under the impression that TryParse expects a string as an input.  Why would you want to TryParse something that is already a time value?

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware times is a String that says "7:58 PM". Is there an easier way to convert that to a DateTime, without parsing?

Comment: @AlexD Maybe, but if I make "7:58 PM" a string literal and try to parse it, it works fine.

Comment: @ictuateAnomaly Are you saying that `times` is a `String`, and the value of the string is _exactly_ `"7:58 PM"`, and `TryParse` fails?

Comment: @AlexD Yes, exactly.

Comment: @ictuateAnomaly Hard to believe :). Try to compare explicitly, just before `TryParse` add `if (times == "7:58 PM") { _breakpoint here_ }`

Comment: @AlexD Would times being an index of a list of strings change anything? I am actually calling times[0], from a list<string> of times. When I compare it, it says they aren't equal, and so I write both times[0] and "7:58 PM" to the debug window, and the result is: 7:58 PM 7:58 PM

Comment: @ictuateAnomaly Then add explicit `if (times[0] == "7:58 PM") { _breakpoint here_ }` and see if you hit the breakpoint right before `TryParse` fails.

Comment: @AlexD Nope, I do not hit the breakpoint.

Comment: @ictuateAnomaly Perfect! So they are different. Let's figure out. Go to Immediate Window and type `times[0][0]`, then `times[0][1]`... What do you see?

Comment: @AlexD (using 9:36 PM now in the list) I see 
oldrectangleTimes[0][0]
8206 '‎'
oldrectangleTimes[0][1]
57 '9'

Comment: @ictuateAnomaly It seems to explain the issue, at least partially. The string `times[0]` has an extra character at the beginning. Decimal code is `8206`. Hex is `200E`. See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm

Comment: @ictuateAnomaly Check if you get the same character on both Phone 7 and Phone 8. I do not know, maybe on your Phone 7 `200E` is considered as a white space and ignored. Do you have anything related to right-to-left languages on these phones?

Comment: @ictuateAnomaly According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character, `200E` is not a whitespace character. So it seems to be correct behavior to fail if time starts with it.

Comment: @AlexD I am using the emulator, and I do not think it contains anything related to RTL.
I added `String newTime = times.Replace((char)0x200E, ' ');` and it works perfectly now, so I assume WP7 does indeed treat 200E as whitespace, whereas 8 does not. 
Thank you so much!

Comment: @AlexD 200E does not show up on the WP7 version regardless then, it seems.

Comment: @ictuateAnomaly It might be still important to see where `200E` comes from on WP8. But it is behind the scope of this question :). Good luck!

Comment: @AlexD My guess is that since WP8 added support for RTL languages, when I save and get the times to and from a text file, that mark is added along the way. Thank you so much!

Comment: Would one of you please be so kind to offer an explanation in an answer so that future readers of this post can benefit?  Thanks.